# Sort tuple by inner elements erlang

Tags: sorting, erlang, tuples

I have a tuple:

```
Data = {
    'F_01_heirId', ["ak238", "ak239", "ak240", "ak241" ...],
    'F_01_0014', ["some text", "some more text", "a some more", "xcuub", ...],
    'F_02_0010', ["azcde", "axvdss" "scssd", "abcdefg as" ...],
    'F_02_0014', ["1222", "1", "1", "10", ...],
    ...
    }
```

Need to sort **Data** tuple by `F_02_0010`, as we are sorting `'F_02_0010'` according to the sorting change the respective elements of other lists too.

Here is the output that is required after sorting:

```
Data =  {
    'F_01_heirId', ["ak241", "ak239", "ak240", "ak238" ...]
    'F_01_0014', ["xcuub", "some more text", "a some more", "some text", ...],
    'F_02_0010', ["abcdefg as", "axvdss", "scssd", "azcde",  ...],
    'F_02_0014', ["10", "1", "1", "1222", ...],
    ...

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your representation of `Data` is not very suitable for the task you want to do. Here are the steps you have to go through:

1. Extract the *column* lists from `Data` and "zip" them into a list of *rows* lists (or tuples). You have to use a custom zip function that can handle more than [2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#zip-2) or [3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#zip3-3) lists:

   ```
   manyzip([L|Ists]) ->
     Fold =
       fun(List, Acc) ->
         lists:zipwith(fun(A,B) -> [A|B] end,List,Acc)
       end,
     Reversed = lists:foldl(Fold, [[E] || E <- L], Ists),
     [lists:reverse(E) || E <- Reversed].
   ```
2. Sort the *rows* on the respective element. You can use [lists:sort/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#sort-2) with a comparison function like `fun(A,B) -> lists:nth(4, A) < lists:nth(4, B) end`, where `4` is the index of `F_02_0010` in the zipped lists.
3. Convert the *rows* back to *columns*. `manyzip/1` can be used as is for this task too!
4. Restore their positions in the tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.  I will simplify  my representation. I will check the answer and will accept the answer.